# Error al serializar objeto en Web Api Core

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Tengo la siguiente clase Company , la cual posee un atributo de tipo List , en el momento que hago el GET a el EndPoint

http://localhost:60391/api/DataCompany?NameCompany=Hp

me devuelve el error:**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Company' with type 'CoreTest.Models.Context.Company'. Path 'Subsidiary[0]'.'**

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Clase Company

```
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "INT")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "VARCHAR(50)")]
        public string NameCompany { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 3, TypeName = "VARCHAR(50)")]
        public string BusinessBranch { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 4, TypeName = "VARCHAR(50)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 5, TypeName = "VARCHAR(15)")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 6, TypeName = "FLOAT")]
        public float AnnualGross { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 7, TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 8, TypeName = "VARCHAR(10)")]
        public string TypeCompany { get; set; }

        public List<Subsidiary> Subsidiary { get; set; }
    }
```

Clase Subsidiary:

```
 public class Subsidiary
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "INT")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "INT")]
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 3, TypeName = "INT")]
        public int IdCompany { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 4, TypeName = "VARCHAR(50)")]
        public string NameSubsidiary { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 5, TypeName = "VARCHAR(50)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 6, TypeName = "VARCHAR(15)")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 7, TypeName = "FLOAT")]
        public float AnnualGross { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 8, TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 9, TypeName = "VARCHAR(10)")]
        public string TypeSubsidiary { get; set; }

    }
```

Metodo :

```
  [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("GetClient")]
        public string  GetClient (string NameCompany)
        {
            string response = EngineValue.NoData;
            if (NameCompany == string.Empty || NameCompany == null)
            {
                response = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString(); ;
                return response;
            }
            EngineDb Metodo = new EngineDb();
            Company client = new Company();
            client = Metodo.GetClient(NameCompany, context);
            if (client == null)
                return response;

           return response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client);
        }
```

Comment: Cual es la estructura de el Json que quiere obtener o enviar a el API??

Comment: La estructura esta descrita en la clase company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu objeto esta haciendo un loop infinito:
Company -> Subsidiary -> Company -> Subsidiary...

Intenta poniendo esto en tu metodo de Register en la clase WebApiConfig que se encuentra en la carpeta de App_Start.

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Si ya esta la configuracion, solamente agrega esa propiedad