# Proyecto MVC sin clase WebApiConfig para colocar json configuration

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Tengo varias Clases que genera el entity framework y se necesitan ser serializadas
asi;

```
 string OldVersion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

pero me resulta el mensaje :

> Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

he consultado y encuentro que se debe tener una clase WebApiConfig que no existe en el proyecto que estoy modificando, y colocar las siguientes lineas de codigo para evitar el [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284767/error-al-serializar-objeto-en-web-api-core)

```
 var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

hay otra forma de agregar esas lineas directamente en el web.config u otra forma para evitar dicho error?

uso Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Que tipo de proyecto es el tuyo?, un Web API 2 de ASP.NET?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta es MVC asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza la **sobrecarga** del método `SerializeObject` para indicarle las opciones de serialización.

Sería algo así:

```
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Formatting.Indented,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            }
        );
```

Si lo quieres hacer a nivel **global** (o sea para toda la aplicación), puedes configurarlo en el método `Application_Start()` del `Global.asax`.

Sería algo así:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        };
    }
```

Comment: Excellente! solo tuve que adicionar unos [JsonIgnore] a algunos campos :D ;)